# In C#, is there out-of-the-box way to build a 3-way lookup table?

Tags: c#, lookup

I have an in-memory "table" that might looks something like this:

```
Favorite#  Name        Profession
---------  ----------  ------------------
3          Names.Adam  Profession.Baker
9          Names.Bob   Profession.Teacher
7          Names.Carl  Profession.Coder
7          Names.Dave  Profession.Miner
5          Names.Fred  Profession.Teacher
```

And what I want to do, is do quick and efficient lookups, using any of the 3 fields.
In other words, I want:

- `myTable[3]` and `myTable[Names.Adam]` and `myTable[Professions.Baker]` to all return `{3,Names.Adam,Profession.Baker}`
- `myTable[Profession.Teacher]` to return both `{9,Names.Bob,Profession.Teacher}` and `{5,Names.Fred,Profession.Teacher}`.

The table is built during runtime, according to the actions of the user, and cannot be stored in a database since it is used in sections in which database connectivity cannot be guaranteed.

Right now, I "simply" (hah!) store this using 3 uber-Dictionaries, each keyed using one of the columns (FavoriteNumber, Name, Profession), and each value in the uber-Dictionaries holding 2 Dictionaries which are themselves keyed with each of the remaining columns (so the values in the "Name" uber-dictionary are of the type `Dictionary<FavoriteNumber,Profession[]>` and `Dictionary<Profession, FavoriteNumber[]>`

This requires 2 lookups in 2 Dictionaries, and another traverse of an array (which usually holds 1 or 2 elements.)

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? I don't mind spending extra memory, since the table is likely to be small (no more than 20 entries) but I'm willing to sacrifice a little CPU to make it more readily maintainable code...

Comment: shouldn't your first example by myTable[3]?

Comment: For 20 rows, just use linear search - it'll be faster than a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really however using a dictionary, but if you create a collection of classes like this

```
class Person {
    public int FavoriteNumber;
    public string Name;
    public string Profession;
}
```

you can use LINQ to search the collections.

```
IList<Person> people = /* my collection */;
var selectedPeople = people.Where(p => p.FavoriteNumber = 3);
var selectedPeople2 = people.Where(p => p.Name == "Bob");
var selectedPeople3 = people.Where(p => p.Profession = "Teacher");
```

or if you prefer the normal LINQ syntax

```
var selectedPeople4 = from p in people
                      where p.Name == "Bob"
                      select p;
```

Each of these `selectedPeople` variables will be typed as `IEnumerable<Person>` and you can use a loop to search through them.

Comment: The downside to this is that you're exposing your representation and if IList isn't good enough, it's painful to refactor.

Comment: And because it's an IList<> it can also do lookups by index as the OP requested. eg, people[0] = {3, "Adam", "Baker"} etc

Comment: @plinth IList<T> is just a holder for a collection, really what part of IList you want when dealing with LINQ is IEnumerable<T>.  Everything else is handled by LINQ and it opens up a wider possibility of queries.

Comment: @Luke you can also change it to whatever type you want by calling .ToArray(), .ToList(), etc.

Comment: This is the best answer, unfortunately I'm barred from using C# 3.0 constructs on this project. (No, I don't know why.)

Answer (score 6):

For 20 rows, just use [linear scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515887/in-c-is-there-out-of-the-box-way-to-build-a-3-way-lookup-table/515921#515921) - it will be the most efficient in every way.

For larger sets; hzere's an approach using LINQ's `ToLookup` and delayed indexing:

```
public enum Profession {
    Baker, Teacher, Coder, Miner
}
public class Record {
    public int FavoriteNumber {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Profession Profession {get;set;}
}
class Table : Collection<Record>
{
    protected void Rebuild()
    {
        indexName = null;
        indexNumber = null;
        indexProfession = null;
    }
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();
        Rebuild();
    }
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Record item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        Rebuild();
    }
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        Rebuild();
    }
    protected override void SetItem(int index, Record item)
    {
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        Rebuild();
    }
    ILookup<int, Record> indexNumber;
    ILookup<string, Record> indexName;
    ILookup<Profession, Record> indexProfession;
    protected ILookup<int, Record> IndexNumber {
        get {
            if (indexNumber == null) indexNumber = this.ToLookup(x=>x.FavoriteNumber);
            return indexNumber;
        }
    }
    protected ILookup<string, Record> IndexName {
        get {
            if (indexName == null) indexName = this.ToLookup(x=>x.Name);
            return indexName;
        }
    }
    protected ILookup<Profession, Record> IndexProfession {
        get {
            if (indexProfession == null) indexProfession = this.ToLookup(x=>x.Profession);
            return indexProfession;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Record> Find(int favoriteNumber) { return IndexNumber[favoriteNumber]; }
    public IEnumerable<Record> Find(string name) { return IndexName[name]; }
    public IEnumerable<Record> Find(Profession profession) { return IndexProfession[profession]; }
}
```

Comment: You're probably right that linear scanning is the best way for such a small set, since my metric for best also includes "time spent maintaining the code".

Answer (score 5):

I think the way to do this is to write your own object that has

```
public ICollection<Record> this[int] { get; }
public ICollection<Record> this[Profession] { get; }
public ICollection<Record> this[Names] { get; }
```

where record is a class that holds your elements.

Internally, you keep a List and each indexer does List.FindAll() to get what you need.

Comment: Since the OP states 20 rows, this is the most efficient option in every way

Answer (score 4):

Nothing out-of-the-box (except perhaps a DataTable). Nevertheless, it can be accomplished in a more simple way that what you've got:

Create a class to hold the data:

```
class PersonData {
   public int FavoriteNumber;
   public string Name;
   public string Profession;
}
```

Then keep 3 dictionaries that point to the same reference:

```
PersonData personData = new PersonData();
Dictionary<int, PersonData> ...;
Dictionary<string, PersonData> ...;
Dictionary<string, PersonData> ...;
```

I'd recommend encapsulating all of this into a facade class that hides the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an [sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) database as the backing? With sqlite you even have the option of building an in-memory db.